# How to insert foreach loop in a string PHP element?

Tags: php

I have a PHP string element

```
$element = "
    <div class='elements'>
        <div class='elementName'>El Name</div>
        <div class='elementImage'><img src='image1.png'></div>
        <div class='elementOptions'>
            <select>
                <option value='null' selected>Select an option</option>
                
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
";
```

What I want to do is insert this foreach loop in the space under the select option

```
$sql =  $conn -> prepare("SELECT elementOptions FROM elements");
$sql -> execute();
$result = $sql -> get_result();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $options = explode(",", $row['elementOptions']);
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
    }
}
```

*NOTE THAT THE elementOptions EQUALS THIS STRING (option1,option2,option3,option4)

I have tried to stop the element by adding this--> "; after the option with the null value and then start a new element with the rest of the code and the combine them in a separated element like

```
$element = $element1 . $element2
```

but this did not work, so my question is how can I create a dynamic PHP element with a foreach loop inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in this way

```
<?php

$element = "
    <div class='elements'>
        <div class='elementName'>El Name</div>
        <div class='elementImage'><img src='image1.png'></div>
        <div class='elementOptions'>
            <select>
                <option value='null' selected>Select an option</option>\n";

                // I use just $row for simplify in this example 
    
                $row = ["elementOptions" => "option1,option2,option3,option4"];
                $options = explode( "," , $row["elementOptions"] );
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $element.="\t\t\t<option value='$option'>$option</option>\n";
                }
      
$element.="\t\t</select>
        </div>
    </div>";

echo $element;
echo "\n\n";
?>
```

output:

```
 <div class='elements'>
        <div class='elementName'>El Name</div>
        <div class='elementImage'><img src='image1.png'></div>
        <div class='elementOptions'>
            <select>
                <option value='null' selected>Select an option</option>
                        <option value='option1'>option1</option>
                        <option value='option2'>option2</option>
                        <option value='option3'>option3</option>
                        <option value='option4'>option4</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To notice :  \t  to indent the output code correctly

Answer (score 0):

In php files you can have normal <html> elements and php logic, which will be interpreted and executed server-side.

You need to use php tags to include php code between your html elements like this

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="elements">
        <div class="elementName">El Name</div>
        <div class="elementImage"><img src="image1.png"></div>
        <div class="elementOptions">
            <select>
                <option value="null" selected>Select an option</option>
```

```php
                <php
                  $sql =  $conn -> prepare("SELECT elementOptions FROM elements");
                  $sql -> execute();
                  $result = $sql -> get_result();
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $options = explode(",", $row['elementOptions']);
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                      echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
                    }
                  }
                ?>
```

```html
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```